# New Facebook App Error "Check Your Connection..."

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook app on my WordPress website that just stopped working and is giving me the below message on connect. I'm definitely connected to the network and other users are experiencing the same issue. Any ideas on where I can begin to look for the error?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like this might be outputting a rather generic error message, that does not necessarily fit the actual cause. My guess would be that one of the API calls in the background runs into an error, probably due to the amount of changes Facebook has made, but this doesn’t pass the actual API error message on to the user/ frontend.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try scanning the developer changes